# making ionic project with firebase on yeoman

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, generator, bower, yeoman

there is yeoman generate for ionic and firebase and I know how to make them with yeoman-generator BUT I want ionic + firebase project.

some [solution[1]](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-07-25-ionic-simple-login.html) [[2]](http://junereycasuga.github.io/blog/2014/06/21/wiring-up-a-back-end-to-your-angularjs-app-using-firebase/) told me that making ionic project and add firebase js file by my hand, but I think firebasee can be added by bower or something easy way to go though.

should i generate inoic project and add firebase though bower?
should i generate firebase project and add ionic though bower?

which one is better way to make it? and what command should i use for this?

Answer (score -1):

TLDR: Long story short, don't use yeoman. It's pretty easy to do it without yeoman.

---

I'd recommend setting up an ionic project, add the firebase.js files, link to it in your index.html, and add the firebase components to your module/relevant controllers. You'll find great step by step instructions here:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html

They won't tell you this up front, but you'll also want to look at the angularfire API here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html

In the Ionic guild they'll show you `$firebaseArray`, but that's it. For things like `$firebaseObject`, those docs are found in the angularfire API.

I'd forget yeoman to be honest. I'm sure you can set up custom projects for yeoman, but I wouldn't bother.